Murderous wife is murdered by a mute housekeeper
I saw this old movie 20 years ago. I remember it's about a rich man who falls in love with a woman but the woman is interested only to his money and plans with her friend (and probably lover) to kill him. They try to tamper with the brakes to simulate a car accident but he survives without any injury, then they kill him in a boat (I don't remember how).
But the woman is also killed by a strange woman who is mute and works as housekeeper for the rich man, in the sauna. Someone knows the title?
Release year: 1970-1977
Format: probably TV movie
Country: USA

Sounds like you're after the obscure House of Terror from 1973.

Lovely young nurse Jennifer Andrews (ravishing brunette beauty Jennifer Bishop) is hired by nice guy millionaire Emmett Kramer (Mitchell Gregg) to take care of his mean and cranky semi-invalid wife Marsha (an excruciatingly shrill and unpleasant portrayal by Jaquelyn Hyde). After Jennifer's sleazeball boyfriend Mark Alden (an effectively smooth turn by Arell Blanton) kills Marsha in a staged suicide, Mark persuades Jennifer to marry Emmett for his sizable fortune.

They try to kill him and make it look like an accident by cutting the brake lines in his car, and he also has an old mute housekeeper called Norma.

